# Smallest possible volume of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help here..
A right-angled triangle with vertices $(0,−b),(3,0),(0,a)$,
where $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers, is rotated about the line $x=4\ $.

What is the smallest possible volume of the solid?

---

I assume the easiest way of solving this is by using coordinates of the centroid of a triangle and Pappus's Theorem.

$$V=2\pi r A, \ \text{where $r$ is the perpendicular distance from the centroid of the triangle to the the line $x=4$, which is equal to 3}$$
$$A=\int_0^3 \frac{b(x-3)}{3} \, \mathrm dx -\int_0^3\frac{a(x-3)}{3} \, \mathrm dx $$

A can also be given by $A=\frac{GH}2$

and from Pythagoras we know that $ab=9$

I've tried to connect all this information but the answer I end up with is wrong. Can anyone see where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the exact volume.  The area is $\frac{3}{2}(a + b)$ (because the height of the "top" triangle is $a$ with base length 3; the height of the "bottom" triangle is $b$ with base length 3).  And yes, the distance is 3 to $x=4$. So the volume is $2\pi(3)\frac{3}{2}(a + b) = 9\pi(a+b)$.

If you are adding the restriction that $ab=9$ then recall that for any non-negative $x, y$, that $(x+y)/2 \ge \sqrt{xy}$ (this is called the *Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality*).  So in your case $a+b \ge 2\sqrt{9} = 6$.  Hence the minimum volume is $54\pi$.

Comment: Thanks! however, we haven't learned the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality. Isn't there another way of doing that step?

Comment: $(a+b)^2=(a-b)^2+4ab\geq 4ab$.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of the resulting solid as a cylinder with two frusta cut out.
The volume of a frustum with height $h$, big radius $R$ and little radius $r$ is $\displaystyle V = \frac{\pi h}{3} (R^2 + Rr + r^2)$.

Let $A = (0,-b)$, $B = (3,0)$, and $C = (0,a)$. We can see fairly easily that $B$ has to be the right angle in triangle $ABC$. Hence, we are given that $9 + b^2 + 9 + a^2 = (a + b)^2$, or $ab = 9$.

The height of the cylinder is $a + b$, and the radius is $4$. Therefore, the volume of the cylinder is $\pi 4^2 (a+b) = 16 (a+b) \pi$.
The volume of the top frustum is $\displaystyle \frac{\pi a}{3} (4^2 + 4*1 + 1^2) = 7 a \pi$.
The volume of the bottom frustum is $\displaystyle \frac{\pi b}{3} (4^2 + 4*1 + 1^2) = 7 b \pi$.
Subtracting the frusta from the cylinder, we get that the volume of the solid is $9 (a+b) \pi$.

Because $ab = 9$, $\displaystyle a+b = a + \frac{9}{a}$. Taking a derivative of this with respect to $a$, we get $\displaystyle \frac{d}{da} \left(a + \frac{9}{a}\right) = 1 - \frac{9}{a^2} = 0$, which makes $a = b = 3$. Plugging this back in, we get $a + b = 6$, and $V = 54 \pi$.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a way of solving this using Pappu's Theorem and coordinates of centroids?

Comment: Yes, [Pappus's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_centroid_theorem) also works well for this. The area of the triangle is $\displaystyle A = \frac{3(a+b)}{2}$, and the centroid is at $\displaystyle \left(1,\frac{a-b}{3}\right)$, so the distance traveled becomes $\displaystyle (4-1)*2\pi = 6\pi$. The volume then becomes $V = Ad = \frac{3(a+b)}{2} \cdot 6\pi = 9(a+b)\pi$. And then you still have to figure out how to minimize $a+b$.

Comment: 2012ssohn, How did you find the centroid location to be (1,a−b/3) ?

Comment: The centroid of a triangle with coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3},\frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}\right)$.